# Connect to Azure Postgres database using Knex.js and Objection.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, knex.js

I've been trying to connect to my azure postgres database remotely with a node API. I'm using the latest version of node, objection.js, knex.js and pg.

My host address is (databasePath) :

`project-name.database.windows.net`

I've setup a wrapper to help with the SQL connection. My connection parameters are defined in a .env file. Whenever I try to connect using the config, I get the following exception :

`Unhandled rejection error: Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format.
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/Eddie/projects/Giggle-Node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/Eddie/projects/Giggle-Node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:379:19)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/Eddie/projects/Giggle-Node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:547:20)`

If I try to use the connection string, the DNS is unable to resolve the provided address. I've tried with two separate variations of the connection string in the form of :

`postgres://userName@myHost:passWord@myHost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dbName?ssl=true`

and

`postgres://userName:passWord@myHost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dbName?ssl=true`

The Exception is :

`Unhandled rejection Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)`

My wrapper is as follows

```js
const { Model } = require( "objection" );
const Knex = require( "knex" );
const dotenv = require( "dotenv" );

dotenv.config();
class ObjectionSQLHelper
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.SQLDatabaseType = process.env.SQL_VARIANT;
        this.databasePath = process.env.DB_PATH;
        this.dataBaseName = process.env.DB_NAME;
        this.databasePort = process.env.DB_PORT;
        this.databaseUserName = process.env.DB_USER_NAME;
        this.databasePassword = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;

    }

    get connectionSchema()
    {
        const knexSchema =
        {
            client: this.SQLDatabaseType,
            connection: {
                //connectionString: this.connectionString,
                userName: this.databaseUserName,
                passWord: this.databasePassword,
                server: this.databasePath,
                host: this.databasePath,
                options:
                {
                    database: this.dataBaseName,
                    encrypt: true,
                    port: this.dataBasePort,
                    ssl: true
                }
            },
            debug: true
        }
        
        return knexSchema;
    }

    get connectionString()
    {
        return `postgres://${ this.databaseUserName }:${ this.databasePassword }@${ this.databasePath }.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/${ this.dataBaseName }?ssl=true`
    }

    connect()
    {
        this.knexConnection = Knex( this.connectionSchema );
        Model.knex( this.knexConnection );
    }
}

const objectionHelperSinglton = new ObjectionSQLHelper();
objectionHelperSinglton.connect();
```

Is there a problem with my configuration or connection string?
I've also added a firewall exception for my current IPv4 on my azure DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Objection and Knex for a few years now, and I have never seen a class wrapper around them as a singleton. However, accepting that at face value that it works, I believe your issue is with the connection string. You can't use a connection string for Azure Postgres Service because the default and required Azure Postgres user name uses `@` to specify the host after your username that you created. Thus, the connection string won't work because the `@` is supposed to separate the username from the host, and since they use it in the user name, it will break the connection string, which seems to be the source of your error message. I don't believe there's a way around this. I put an example below. Notice the extra `@`, which would throw off the connection string. I would recommend following the knex documentation for this [here](https://knexjs.org/#Installation-client).

Azure Postgres Username's are: `user_defined_user_name@user_defined_azure_postgres_database_service_name`

You're connection string would look like this: `postgres://user_defined_user_name@user_defined_azure_postgres_database_service_name@myHost:passWord@myHost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dbName?ssl=true`

While I think what I listed above is the issue, here are some other things to try:

- If this isn't the case, is it possible that your environment variables are working correctly? Have you console logged them?
- Have you copied your username and database URL directly from the Azure Portal making sure to not have any additional white space on the ends?
- Have you set up your firewall rules to enable all IPs (for testing purposes to verify that the firewall isn't the issue)?

Comment: I've console logged everything and my env variables are  working fine. I'll try that approach when I have access to my machine. Can you clarify what user_defined_azure_postgres_database_service_name is supposed to be?

Comment: My server url is `user_defined_server_name.postgres.database.azure.com`.
My admin user name is `user_defined_admin_name@user_defined_server_name`. Those were both defined when you created the database server. You can find them by going to the Azure Portal and selecting your database server. It would be in the top on the Overview tab under Essentials.